# ln will not create symlinks to nonexistent targets / target without permission

Tags: files, permissions, symlink, ln

First of all please note that I'm on a shared server and I don't have root access, so anything involving su or sudo would not be possible.

AFAIK ln and Linux should not even bother checking whether the target of a symlink exists or whether the user has permissions to access it. Yet for some reason this happens:

```
user@example.com [~/tmp/test]# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 Aug 17 14:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 user user 4096 Aug 17 14:52 ../
user@example.com [~/tmp/test]# ln -s target a
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'a': No such file or directory
user@example.com [~/tmp/test]# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 Aug 17 14:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 user user 4096 Aug 17 14:52 ../
user@example.com [~/tmp/test]# touch target
user@example.com [~/tmp/test]# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 Aug 17 14:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 user user 4096 Aug 17 14:52 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    0 Aug 17 14:53 target
user@example.com [~/tmp/test]# ln -s target a
user@example.com [~/tmp/test]# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 Aug 17 14:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 user user 4096 Aug 17 14:52 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user    6 Aug 17 14:53 a -> target
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    0 Aug 17 14:53 target
user@example.com [~/tmp/test]#
```

As you can see ln will refuse to create a symlink to a nonexistent target.

Also, it will refuse to create symlinks to targets that I don't have read permissions to, targets that are in directories that I don't have read permissions to and even files that I do have permissions to I don't have read permissions to any of the parent directories all the way to the root directory.

Also I've tried using Python's os.symlink() function and it experiences the same issue.

I'm really puzzled here.

Comment: Note this doesn't say `target: no such file or directory`, it specifically complains about `a`.  The error isn't about target, it's about not being able to create `a`.  Now why would it not be able to create or find a file?  Maybe its parent directory has a problem?  This is how I would reason and get to telcoM's answer.  Alternate possibility: the filesystem hates your link.

Comment: What's the version of linux kernel and  libc? What type of filesystem is  `~/tmp/test` on (output of `df -T .` from within that directory for instance)

Comment: I'd suspect that's a remote FS mounted from a non-Unix system and where symlinks are emulated on top of some similar feature of that remote system. What happens if you remove `target`? Is the `a` symlink also removed?

Comment: And what if the target is renamed? Can you make symlinks to files in directories you don't have access to?

Answer (score 5):

Have you perhaps used another session to delete the directory you are in?

I can reproduce the error message with:

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp/test
cd ~/tmp/test
<< in another window: rmdir ~/tmp/test >>
ln -s target a
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'a': No such file or directory
```

In such a situation, even trying to start another shell will cause an error message:

```
bash
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

In other words, the error message from `ln` could mean that the **target directory** no longer exists. The directory is treated like a deleted-but-still-open file: your shell already has it open, so the shell can still access it, but any new processes cannot.

Even `cd ..` will result in an error:

```
cd ..
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
cd ~/tmp
ls
<< directory is empty >>
```

Comment: You wouldn't get the same `ls -la` output though

Comment: The OP also say they can create the symlink if they create the target first, which doesn't tie up

Comment: The directory does exist (otherwise ls wouldn't have worked either).